Transaction on solscan show wrong address
I have an account on Phantom wallet, I have an asset on it (memecoin based on Solana network).
I create new account, try to send my asset to new account and it show failed.
When I checked the tx on solscan, I see seem the destination address on  tx is different with my new account. Is it correct?



When creating a new account to receive tokens. You would first have to pay the other account some SOL to make it rent exempt. Then you can transfer assets. Around 0.02 SOL is ideal.
